# Im trying to decrypt a message that has been encrypted by a randomly generated 8 character key

Tags: python, encryption

```
def fnDecrypt():

    key = raw_input("Please type the offset factor key: ")
    name = raw_input("Please enter the name of the file you want to decrypt: ")
    offset_factor = key

    encrypted_message = open(name,'r')
    message = encrypted_message.read()
    print "The contents of the file you are decrypting is: " + message
    for c in message:
            number = ord(c)
            if c != " ":
                    number -= offset_factor
                    if number  > 126:
                           number = number + 94
                       new_character = chr(number)
            encrypted_message -= new_character
    print 1

    print encrypted_message

    return;
```

this code is supposed to decrypt a encrypted message using the same eight character key that was used to encrypt it.At the minute i have this error message : UnboundLocalError: local variable 'new_character' referenced before assignment

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You have provided some code, but haven't said what you want to achieve and how the code currently behaves. Please add example inputs, outputs and expected outputs to your question.

Comment: when i run the code i get this error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'int' and 'str' , but i cant manage to get this code to decrypt an encrypted message for example i encrypt the message "the moon was scary" with a generated key which gives me the offset factor of 57 then it encrypts to "OC@ HJJI R<N N><MTC"  i want to now decrypt it using the same offset factor

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the stacktrace and add the other missing information. (What is this code supposed to do?)

Comment: try changing `offset_factor = key` to `offset_factor = int(key)`

Comment: this is an answer on how you could implement a vigenere cipher: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31340565/4954037

Comment: @hiroprotagonist It's a caesar cipher.

Comment: i got a new error message Davide when i tried that, UnboundLocalError: local variable 'new_character' referenced before assignment

Comment: well, a caesar cipher is a vigenere cipher where the length of the key is 1.

Comment: Again, please add the stacktrace (error) to your question. Comments may be deleted at any time.

Answer (score 2):

Your error "`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'new_character' referenced before assignment`" is caused because you access the `new_character` variable before you define it.

This can be seen when we focus on this part of your code:

```
if number > 126:
    number = number + 94
    new_character = chr(number)
encrypted_message -= new_character
```

As you see, you define `new_character` variable **inside** the `if number > 126:` block, yet you use it outside the `if` in `encrypted_message -= new_character`.

When your variable `number` is smaller than 126, you never enter the `if` block, thus you  never define `new_character`.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29

Answer (score -1):

the stacktrace "**UnboundLocalError: local variable 'new_character' referenced before assignment**" happens typically when you try to use a variable that, to the computer, hasnt been referenced.

[UnBoundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29533098/unboundlocalerror-local-variable-referenced-before-assignment-python)

your **if** conditional isnt true, and you're trying to use the variable **new_character** before its referenced. This is why its important to also write an **else** for debugging purposes.

```
     for c in message:
        number = ord(c)
        if c != " ":
                number -= offset_factor
                if number  > 126:
                       number = number + 94
                else:
                     print "Something went wrong"
                new_character = chr(number)
        encrypted_message -= new_character
```

Comment: Whoever downvoted, could you tell me why so I could improve this and future answers?

Comment: I did. Call me a dick, but I think @MarkusMeskanen's answer is clear and readable, and yours - not as much, even after re-reading it a couple of times. It also lacks the word "scope", which is what OP should read about. Terrible spelling doesn't help either, sorry. Nothing personal, I've written worse answers - and I'd definitely reverse my vote if you could top Markus' answer :)

Comment: I dont think you're a dick. Just wanted to know how I could improve my future answers. thank you.